# How do I get all the endpoint URLs from my WordPress site? I need to get for login page, logout page , forgot password page etc

Tags: wordpress, api, endpoint

My android developer wants all the endpoint URLs from WordPress site with method and parameters

I have tried https://wordpresssite.com/wp-json, it lists only some URLs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no such things like login, logout and forgot password for WordPress API. WordPress authorize you by the `nonce` set in request header when sending request.

You can read more at:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762